# Add more devices to iOS Developer account

Tags: iphone, ios

In our office we are using developer account to register devices, As you all know using developer account we can add only 100 devices per year, we have already used 90 of it. we just have 10 devices more and we have 6 more months for renewal date. can you anyone guide me, whether i should buy a new developer account or is there any possible to add more devices into my current account? Any help much appreciated.
Thanks!
With Regards,
P. Arun Ganesh

Comment: Try delete the old devices that you dont need anymore.

Comment: I have deleted the old devices, but the number of available devices (remaining device to be add) has not updated. still it shows 10.

Comment: @R.A: That won't work. On your provisioning portal, they specifically said "You can register up to 100 devices per year for development purposes. Any devices added, then later removed, still count towards your maximum number of registered devices per year."

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, Apple will sometimes grant extensions to the 100 device / year limit. Give them a call.

Comment: In the event that they do not grant it, then the company may switch to an enterpise developer membership. That is a bit more expensive though but enables you guys to distribute the apps to more than 100 (test) devices.

Comment: Can we able distribute our app to client (testers) like developer account? And also what is the main difference between Developer account and enterprise account? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can still distribute to testers like the developer account. The enterprise account gives you more freedom & lifts the 100 device limit.

Comment: @pdesantis did you get any extensions so far?

Comment: Yes, my company did, although I wasn't really involved in the process.

Answer (score 3):

The development devices are meant for developing and testing your apps only. It is not a way to distribute your apps, especially not to the customers. And once you register a development device with apple, even you delete it from your Provisioning Portal, it will still count towards your 100, so please be careful.

What you want do is contact Apple, tell them you do need more than 100 development devices and see if they can give you more.